# Explanation on flutter nameRoute

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web

Hello please can someone explain this to me. I got it in a tutorial but the explanation is not clear. my question is why passing 1 in to a path[1] array its kinna confusing. I understand this: **final path = settings.name.split('/');** but the **final title** got me lost and this **books.firstWhere((it)** is **it** a keyword in flutter please someone help me understand.

```
 ///Generate parameterized route --> e.g: detail/some book title
  generateRoute(RouteSettings settings) {
    final path = settings.name.split('/');
    final title = path[1];

    Book book = books.firstWhere((it) => it.title == title);
    return MaterialPageRoute(
      settings: settings,
      builder: (context) => Detail(book),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: see https://dart.dev/codelabs/iterables#example-using-firstwhere and https://dart.dev/codelabs/iterables#filtering, it is a good idea to read the whole article though...

Comment: ``it`` is not a keyword. It's a variable with the resulting element's value. You can replace it with another name of your choice.